# Multiple headers required in Swashbuckle for OpenAPI authentication

Tags: swashbuckle

I have an API that requires two headers, a "user ID" and a "secret". I am failing to find a way to get them listed in the OpenAPI output as both needed, they are shown as separate options for authorization. OpenAPI says it can do this for [Multiple API Keys](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/api-keys/) (leave out a dash) but I cannot find a way to specify that the two are related in code. Is this possible in Swashbuckle? (Am using .Net Core 3.1)

```
          options.AddSecurityDefinition("appkey", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                Description = "Unique application key (user ID)",
                In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                Name = CustomAuthenticationOptions.ApplicationKeyHeaderName,
                Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey
            });
            options.AddSecurityDefinition("secret", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                Description = "Secret key (password)",
                In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                Name = CustomAuthenticationOptions.SecretKeyHeaderName,
                Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
            });
```

Comment: Turns out this is a bug in the Swagger UI, that has been there years and no one cares enough to fix. Me neither it turns out.